# What is the longest-running manga series that has already ended before september 2016?

Tags: manga-history

Ah! My Goddess manga has run from september 1988 to june 2014, and that is 25 years, 9 months.

Of the manga series that have already ended by this posting (before september 2016), what is the longest-running one?

Is it Ah! My Goddess? Or is there an even longer one?

I'm more interested in the time between the first and the last chapter, but if you can **in addition to** make a point for the one with more chapters, that is also acceptable

Comment: I thought for sure this was a duplicate or at least related to a question that was already asked, but I looked around and didn't find anything, so +1 and I'm interested to see the answers.

Comment: Off the top of my head, Sazae-san already beats it out at 28 years (1946-1974). I'm sure there's other old stuff out there that ran even longer. From [this ja.wikipedia page](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/100%E5%B7%BB%E4%BB%A5%E4%B8%8A%E5%88%8A%E8%A1%8C%E3%81%97%E3%81%A6%E3%81%84%E3%82%8B%E6%BC%AB%E7%94%BB%E4%BD%9C%E5%93%81), there's apparently a baseball manga called "Abu-san" that ran for 41 years (1973-2014).

Comment: Longest running as in longest continuous running or what? Please clarify.

Comment: @AyaseEri time between first and last chapter. It is assumed that some series might have some long hiatus.

Comment: [Kochikame](http://www.animenewsnetwork.com/news/2016-09-03/osamu-akimoto-kochikame-manga-ends-on-september-17-after-40-years-of-serialization/.106073) is ending this month (September 2016) and is usually given as the manga series with the most chapters/volumes (its final volume will be Volume 200). Chiisana Koi no Monogatari still wins for span of years, though; Kochikame started in 1976, so it's been going for a mere 40 years.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The series mentioned by senshin in the comments are hard to beat. But here is a new record:

Chiisana Koi no Monogatari (小さな恋のものがたり) ran for **52 years**, from 1962 to 2014.

[image][image]

It was created by Chikako Mitsuhashi and published by Manga Time. A total of 43 were published.

Sources: [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_manga_series_by_volume_count) and [myanimelist](https://myanimelist.net/manga/75265/Chiisana_Koi_no_Monogatari).

According to the same wikipedia article, the record to most chapters seem to go to Sazae-san, with **6477**, and the one for more volumes published to Nijitte Monogatari with **111**.

Comment: Good find (but note that _Kochikame_ is still ongoing, and so probably not what OP is looking for). It's important to keep in mind, though, that the amount of content in "one chapter" or "one volume" can vary a lot, both by genre and over time. Page count is probably a better measure of "which series has the most content" (though, again, the amount of content in a page varies, too, albeit less so).

Comment: @senshin You are right. Sazae-san actually has more chapters, and ended in 1994. I've edited accordingly. I also agree that page count is a better measure for amount of content.

Comment: @senshin that is why i worded the question to mention time lapse between episodes. And I put a stop at the month of posting, to exclude ongoing series. It somehow breaks SE timelessness requirements, but it can remain as a research reference.